# I have this permanent error with my React.js code, how to fix this?

Tags: reactjs, file, import, export

I am beginner on React and I get some errors with my code on dashboard page and imports on the index page. Please can you help me fix this ?

[Error shown on Dashboard page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrAmQ.png)

[Error shown on Index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtsk5.png)

Comment: Seem to be syntax errors... Have you taken a look at the beginner code snippets here: https://reactjs.org/ -- you will be able to fix it yourself after that :)

Comment: Please post code snippets directly in the question. Linked pages and images can and eventually will break and someone viewing this in the future will not get the full picture.